# Trace an image in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I Wrote this python script to trace the image. But it is throwing an error. It is showing **"IndexError: index 181 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 181"** where my image size is **181x158**. I decreased the range in order to rectify this error but, no use.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
global p
a = cv2.imread('t.png',0);
b = (255 -a);
c = np.asarray(b);
p = np.count_nonzero(c)
[ay , ax] = c.shape;
z = np.zeros(c.shape, dtype=np.int)

def startTrace(yt,xt):
    global p
    p = p-1
    z[yt,xt] = 255;
    c[yt,xt] =0;
    if (c[yt, xt+1] > 0):
        startTrace(yt,xt+1)
    elif (c[yt+1,xt+1] > 0):
        startTrace(yt+1,xt+1)
    elif (c[yt+1,xt] > 0):
        startTrace(yt+1,xt)
    elif (c[yt+1,xt-1] >0) :
        startTrace(yt+1,xt-1)
    elif (c[yt,xt-1] >0):
        startTrace(yt,xt-1)
    elif (c[yt-1,xt-1] > 0):
        startTrace(yt-1,xt-1)
    elif (c[yt-1,xt] > 0):
        startTrace(yt-1,xt)
    elif (c[yt-1,xt+1] > 0):
        startTrace(yt-1,xt+1)


while (p > 0):
    for y in range(1,ay-2):
        for x in range(1,ax-2):
            if c[y,x] > 0 :
                startTrace(y,x);
```

Comment: python lists start at zero,   so if alist has length 5, the first item is alist[0] and the last item is alist[4]

Comment: Try to limit the range for `yt` and `xt` in `startTrace`. They may go beyond the size of image, say `ax` and `ay` here.

Comment: What do you mean by trace ? Also your `startTrace` has no base condition and the recursion may run for infinity.

Comment: @ZdaR or crash due to the increasing loop without any bound.

Comment: @ZdaR this code is to trace binary image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you all for your help.
This code is working correctly.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


global p
a = cv2.imread('t.png',0);
[ty,tx] = a.shape;
o = np.zeros((ty+2,tx+2),dtype=np.int)
o[1:ty+1,1:tx+1] = (255 -a);
c = np.asarray(o);
p = np.count_nonzero(c)
[ay , ax] = c.shape;
z = np.zeros(c.shape, dtype=np.int)

def startTrace(yt,xt):
    global p
    cv2.imshow('image',z);
    z[yt,xt] = 255;
    c[yt,xt] =0;
    p = np.count_nonzero(c)
    if((yt < ay-1) and (xt < ax -1)): 
        if (c[yt, xt+1] > 0):
            startTrace(yt,xt+1)
        elif (c[yt+1,xt+1] > 0):
            startTrace(yt+1,xt+1)
        elif (c[yt+1,xt] > 0):
            startTrace(yt+1,xt)
        elif (c[yt+1,xt-1] >0) :
            startTrace(yt+1,xt-1)
        elif (c[yt,xt-1] >0):
            startTrace(yt,xt-1)
        elif (c[yt-1,xt-1] > 0):
            startTrace(yt-1,xt-1)
        elif (c[yt-1,xt] > 0):
            startTrace(yt-1,xt)
        elif (c[yt-1,xt+1] > 0):
            startTrace(yt-1,xt+1)


while (p > 0):
    for y in range(1,ay-2):
        for x in range(1,ax-2):
            if (c[y,x] > 0) :
                startTrace(y,x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that your code is recursive (startTrace calls itself) and you don't know how many times it will call itself. In fact, can you assure that a single call to startTrace() will ever exit? Could startTrace() call startTrace() forever? This would cause a stack overflow eventually. But this is not your problem (yet).

The code fails because each call to startTrace has different parameters (+1, -1) than the original call to startTrace(). Even if call inside the "while" assures that you are not out of bounds, if startTrace() is called recursively, each new call may have the original parameter +1, which eventually will grow to be out of bounds (there is no check inside startTrace() that the parameter is inside the bounds of the image). You should add an if at the beginning of your function to check that xt an yt are inside the bounds of the image.

Anyway, I would suggest to search in OpenCV for a method that does what you want. Take a look at findContours, for example.